# PHP Regex to strip excess punctuation

Tags: php, regex

So basically we need a regex to strip excess punctuation from a string, leaving only one of the punctuation characters.

So:

> This is my awesome string!!!!! Don't you love it???!!??!!

Would result in

> This is my awesome string! Don't you love it?!

I have tried and tried and tried to get this, but I either end up mangling the string or it doesn't work at all.  I'm still learning Regexes so please forgive what is surely a stupid question.

I guess "punctuation" would be pretty much anything that's not A-Za-z0-9

**Edit** It appears that I misunderstood our original requirements.  Using the accepted solution below, how would I adjust it so that no matter what characters you have, the punctuation is limited to the first only?

IE

> ???!!!!!!

would become just

> ?

And

> This is my string!!!?!?!?!? Isn't it great???!?!?!!

would become

> This is my string! Isn't it great?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: So more or less, you want to have a regex which will add only 1 of the character, in the order in which they appear in the end of punctuation?   What about "  ..?!?!?!?!!" would do something like ".?!"

Comment: Yes, basically.  But ? and ! aren't the only punctuation characters.  We've also got *#@%^&*() and etc... and they can appear in any order.  We've just got an issue with over-enthusiastic users and I'd like to calm them down a bit.  I hadn't thought about ?!?!?!?! but yes, that is a good use case that would need to be caught as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the other answers, but should take care of any non `0-9a-zA-Z` characters in any order leaving you with one of each left:

```
$newstring= preg_replace('/([^\w\s])(?=[^\w\s]*\1)/', '', $oldstring);
```

Should turn

```
This is my awesome string!!!!! Don't you love it???!!??!!
```

into

```
This is my awesome string! Don't you love it?!
```

It works by using a positive lookahead to see if the character appears again in this string of punctuation. If it does, it's replaced with the empty string.

Comment: Wow.  Absolutely 100% amazing!  I hadn't heard of positive lookaheads before, so now I've got more reading to do.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It appears that I misunderstood the request from our users.  They would like recurring instances of any punctuation to be trimmed to a single character.

So, (*&@$&&@$&&&!!!@@@**** would become ( and !???!!! would become !

I'm not sure about how to adjust your regex to accomplish this.

Comment: @Kevin I'd use a different regex to accomplish that - maybe something like `preg_replace('/([^\w\s])[^\w\s]*/', '$1', $oldstring)` which looks for any non-alphanumeric character followed by 0 or more non-alphanumeric characters and just returns the first character.

Comment: Again, absolutely amazing.  Is there a good book on Regex or what?  I can do the basic stuff, but things like this just astound me.

Comment: @Kevin I've never read any books on regex so I couldn't recommend one. I learnt what I know mostly from the tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Something like `preg_replace('#([!?])\1+#', '$1')`, perhaps? For example:

```
$t = 'This is my awesome string!!!!! Don\'t you love it???!!??!!';
$u = preg_replace('#([!?])\1+#', '$1', $t);

// to clear out all these '?!?!...' and '!?!?...' sequences.
$u = preg_replace('#(\?!|!\?)\1+#', '$1', $u); 


echo $u; // This is my awesome string! Don't you love it?!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_replace_callback`:

```
preg_replace_callback('/[!?]+/', function($m) {
    $excl = strpos($m[0], '!');
    $ques = strpos($m[0], '?');

    if($excl !== false && $excl <= $ques) {
        return $ques === false ? '!' : '!?';
    } else {
        return $excl === false ? '?' : '?!';
    }
}, $str);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/42WQl6)